# Mongoose - Getting items by property and filtering array of objects

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to create a search function where a user can input a certain query and find all messages that contain that query.

The way I have it set up is when the user clicks search, it sends a query to the database based on the current message they're in.

If I just do `Messages.find()` the data looks like this:

```
const input = [
  {
      "_id": "1",
      "firstName": "John",
      "last_name": "Doe",
      "message_id": "12345",
      "messages": [
          {
              "time": "Thu Aug 05 2021 19:31:15 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)",
              "text": "hey there"
          },
          {
              "time": "Thu Aug 05 2021 19:34:15 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)",
              "text": "what's up"
          },
          {
              "time": "Thu Aug 05 2021 19:37:15 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)",
              "text": "hey"
          },
      ],
      "__v": 0
  },
  {
      "_id": "2",
      "firstName": "Jane",
      "last_name": "Doe",
      "message_id": "12345",
      "messages": [
          {
              "time": "Thu Aug 05 2021 19:32:15 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)",
              "text": "hey buddy"
          },
          {
              "time": "Thu Aug 05 2021 19:35:15 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)",
              "text": "not much, what about you?"
          },
          {
              "time": "Thu Aug 05 2021 19:38:15 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)",
              "text": "hello!"
          },
      ],
      "__v": 0
  },
]
```

I want to search for a specific keyword **"hey"** and return the items that contain the word **"hey"**

```
const expected = [
  {
      "_id": "1",
      "firstName": "John",
      "last_name": "Doe",
      "message_id": "12345",
      "messages": [
          {
              "time": "Thu Aug 05 2021 19:31:15 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)",
              "text": "hey there"
          },
          {
              "time": "Thu Aug 05 2021 19:37:15 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)",
              "text": "hey"
          },
      ],
      "__v": 0
  },
  {
      "_id": "2",
      "firstName": "Jane",
      "last_name": "Doe",
      "message_id": "12345",
      "messages": [
          {
              "time": "Thu Aug 05 2021 19:32:15 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)",
              "text": "hey buddy"
          },
      ],
      "__v": 0
  },
]
```

I'm currently doing it like this, but am wondering if there's a better way or if there's a way to do it with purely Mongoose.

```
  Message.find({message_id})
    .then((messages) => {
      let filtered = messages.map(item => {
        let filteredMessages = item.messages.filter(message => {
          return message.text.toLowerCase().match(new RegExp("\\b" + "hey" + "\\b")) != null;
        });
        return {...item, messages: filteredMessages};
      }).filter(empty => empty.messages.length > 0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey Try this....

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "messages.text": {
        "$regex": ".*hey.*"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$messages"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "messages.text": {
        "$regex": ".*hey.*"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      messages: {
        "$addToSet": {
          time: "$messages.time",
          text: "$messages.text"
        }
      },
      "firstName": {
        $first: "$firstName"
      },
      "last_name": {
        $first: "$last_name"
      },
      "message_id": {
        $first: "$message_id"
      },
      
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      _id: 1
    }
  }
])
```

Output

```
[
  {
    "_id": "1",
    "firstName": "John",
    "last_name": "Doe",
    "message_id": "12345",
    "messages": [
      {
        "text": "hey",
        "time": "Thu Aug 05 2021 19:37:15 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)"
      },
      {
        "text": "hey there",
        "time": "Thu Aug 05 2021 19:31:15 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "2",
    "firstName": "Jane",
    "last_name": "Doe",
    "message_id": "12345",
    "messages": [
      {
        "text": "hey buddy",
        "time": "Thu Aug 05 2021 19:32:15 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rmkZjxLPfCb)